# Access an object properties without casting to a type

Tags: c#, linq

i am using LINQ to entity to return a list of objects

```
            var st = personsList.Select(p => new
            {
                ID = p.Id,
                Key = p.Key,
                Name = p.Name,
                Address = p.Address,
                City = p.City,
                PhoneNumber = p.PhoneNumber
            })
            return st.ToList();
```

after i get the list in another class how can I access each property?

something like

```
foreach(object s in St)
{
    string name = s.Name;
}
```

I have no predefined class to cast the object to it.

Can this be done without having to create a class and cast the object to that class type?

Thanks

Comment: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance.aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter: TL;DR: Just because you can doesn't mean you should. :)

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: Yes, i think jon's title is self-explanatory: _"Horrible grotty hack: returning an anonymous type instance"_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the follwing

```
foreach(object s in St)
{
   Type type = s.GetType();
   PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty("Name");
   if(property !=null)
   {
       string name= (string )property.GetValue(s, null);
   }
}
```

you have to add the namespace System.Reflection to the class

Answer (score 10):

Are you using C# 4? You could try using `dynamic`:

```
foreach(dynamic s in St)
{
    string name = s.Name;
}
```

The risk is, of course, that if you try to access a property that the object doesn't have you'll only find out at runtime.

As an aside, wouldn't it make more sense in this case to actually create a class that has all these properties? You clearly need them in several places and you'd get the benefits of type-safety and compile-time errors.

Answer (score 0):

C# 3.0 has the [`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) type which allows implicit casting.

Comment: It's still strongly typed (the type of `var foo = new Foo()` is `Foo`), and you can't use it to return a value though. Also it's implicit typing, not casting.

Answer (score 0):

The complier is creating you an anonymous type which can be used within the scope of the method. If you need to pass the results of LINQ query around then it’s best to create a domain object to represent that information like PersonSummary and assign the results of the query to that. C# is strongly typed take advantage of that.